# Invoking metadata API call using JSFORCE

Tags: visualforce, metadata-api, jsforce

Consider:

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="true">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Jsforce}"/>
    <input type="file" id="input"></input>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ctrlRead(){
            var selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
            var files = selectedFile.files;
            var conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: '{!$Api.Session_Id}'});
            conn.metadata.retrieve(files,function(error,ref) {
                if (error) {
                   console.log("error");
                }
                else {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(ref));
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <apex:form>
        <div>DEPLOYMENT TOOL</div>
        <apex:commandButton onclick="ctrlRead();" value="Reterive" id="theButton"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I am trying to pass the file to the retrieving metadata API call using JSFORCE to extract the metadata. But I am getting the error

> "INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: No packages or unpackaged specified"

How can I fix this problem?

Here is the next attempt and updated code.

I modified the code and tested it:

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="true">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Jsforce}"/>
    <input type="file" id="input"></input>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ctrlRead(){
            var selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
            var files = selectedFile.files;
            var para = {apiVersion:37.0,packageNames:null,singlePackage:true,specificFiles:files,unpackaged:files};
            var conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: '{!$Api.Session_Id}'});
            conn.metadata.retrieve(para,function(error,ref) {
                if (error) {
                   console.log("error");
                }
                else {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(ref));
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <div>DEPLOYMENT TOOL</div>
        <apex:commandButton onclick="ctrlRead();" value="Reterive" id="theButton"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But now I am getting an error:

> INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: More than 1 package retrieved with single package flag

This is the modified one i am getting success response

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="true">
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Jsforce}"/>
<input type="file" id="input"></input>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function ctrlRead(){ 
        var selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
        var files = selectedFile.files; 
        var para = {apiVersion:37.0,singlePackage:false,unpackaged:files};
         var conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: '{!$Api.Session_Id}'});
         conn.metadata.retrieve(para,function(error,ref) {
             if (error) {
                console.log("error");
             } 
             else {
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(ref));

             } 
      });
     }        
  </script>
 <apex:form >
 <div>DEPLOYMENT TOOL</div>
 <apex:commandButton onclick="ctrlRead();" value="Reterive" id="theButton"/>
 </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: What's the file you're using?

Comment: I am using the package.xml file which contains this following content:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Package xmlns="soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">; <types> <members>Loan</members> <name>FlexiPage</name> </types> <version>29.0</version> </Package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [metadata documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve.htm) for the retrieve call in SFDC, metadata requires any of the below.

1. Package name or list of packages you want to retrieve the metadata info for
2. A package.xml consisting of the list of file names to retrieve

I guess in your case you should create a retrieve Request object which will be pointed to the package.xml file.

The working code is as below.

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="true">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Jsforce}"/>
    <input type="file" id="input"></input>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ctrlRead(){
            var selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
            var files = selectedFile.files;
            var para = {apiVersion:37.0,singlePackage:false,unpackaged:files};
            var conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: '{!$Api.Session_Id}'});
            conn.metadata.retrieve(para,function(error,ref) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("error");
                }
                else {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(ref));
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <div>DEPLOYMENT TOOL</div>
        <apex:commandButton onclick="ctrlRead();" value="Reterive" id="theButton"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I am using the package.xml file  which contains this following content:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Loan</members>
        <name>FlexiPage</name>
    </types>
    <version>29.0</version>
</Package>

Comment: Mohit, you mean to say javascript object or apex wrapper retrieve Request object and pass it to reterive call?

Comment: Yes so you will need to use a javascript object to pass that as a parameter .The request object in JSforce might need you to specify unmanaged .I would console.log the function and figure what is the expected request object format

Comment: I will dig into repo in a while and may add some more explanation